# Dúvida para usar o combobox

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Bom Dia,

Eu tenho um trabalho final da cadeira para desenvolvimento web, aonde eu preciso criar um crud para times, jogadores, criar uma tabela estilo do campeonato brasileiro e criar as rodadas. Ja consegui criar os cruds e a tabela do campeonato mas criar as rodadas esta complicado. Pensei criar um combobox para fazer as partidas e usar textfield para inserir os resultados, criar isso é fácil o problema é como posso fazer ao usar combobox para não permitir o mesmo time duas vezes na mesma rodada e se o valor do textfield depois passo para algum campo do banco de dados. Ou se tiverem uma ideia melhor para dar, agradeço a todos.

Comment: Antes de adicionar o Time consulte no banco se aquiele time ja está na rodada.

Comment: @Krismorte faria um if por exemplo, para ve se akele time esta na rodada,seria isso?

Comment: Sim. Como você não postou seu código fica dificil dar outras ideias. Se você estiver trabalhando com List você pode simplesmente tirar o time da lista e recarregar o Box. Enfim.

Comment: Deixei o note em casa e estou no trabalho no momento mas o que tenho nessa tela  10 combobox  Ex.:  Time A X Time B. Aonde eu insiro um resultado para cada partida. E o combobox é gerado a partir do BD.

Comment: Pelo o que eu to entendendo ai essa tela com os 10 combobox ão precisam existir. Ja que nela será informado os resultados e pra isso a rodada ja deve ter sido cadastrado.
Exemplo 
Rodada A
Time1 xTime2
time3 xtim4
Rodada B
Time1 xTime3
time2 xtim4

Comment: Seria algo do tipo aconteceu hoje a rodada do brasileirão, dai iria por exemplo cadastrar na tela essa rodada com os resultados.
Ex.: Time A 2 x 1 Time C
        Time D 0 x 0 Time B.
O trecho do trabalho que fala sobre o resultado:
 É necessário saber informações sobre jogos e placar e quando o usuário clicar no botão de atualizar deve devolver a tabela de classificação do campeonato
Para realizar esse trabalho pode se usar o conteúdo visto em aula HTML,CSS, PHP, Banco de dado, Jquery,Javascript .

Comment: Então volta de volta ao meu primeiro comentário. Toda vez que cadastrar tem que fazer uma consulta no banco.

Comment: Desculpa a pergunta idiota mas se eu cadastrar Por exemplo o time A como mandante por exemplo quando for escolher o visitante não ia aparecer o Time A de novo? Eu gostaria de restringir isso por que com certeza meu professor vai me pedir essa validação. Obrigado pela sua ajuda e desculpa tomar o teu tempo.

Comment: Carregue o combobox do mandante e adicione um evento nele para carregar o outro box a partir do item selecionado excluindo-o

Comment: Obrigado vou tentar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue um exemplo super básico. Creio que isso vai resolver o seu problema, porém, entenda a lógica.

O JavaScript fica responsável por esconder o option selecionado e replicar nos outros selects. Dessa forma não precisa ficar enviando um post toda vez que seleciona um option

```js
$('.select').on('change', function() {
  var option = $(this).val();
  $('.select').each(function() {
    $(this).find('option').show();
    $(this).find('option[value=' + option + ']').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<form action="#" method="POST">
  <select class='select' name="select[1][]">
    <option>Selecionar</option>
    <option value='A'>A</option>
    <option value='B'>B</option>
    <option value='C'>C</option>
    <option value='D'>D</option>
    <option value='E'>E</option>
  </select>
  <select class='select' name="select[1][]">
    <option>Selecionar</option>
    <option value='A'>A</option>
    <option value='B'>B</option>
    <option value='C'>C</option>
    <option value='D'>D</option>
    <option value='E'>E</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

No PHP =>

```
  <?php
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($_POST);
       echo '</pre>';
       exit;
/* Como o PHP vai capturar =>
    [select] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => A
                        [1] => B
                    )

            )

*/
    ?>
```

OBS: O resultado dessa resposta também é baseado nos comentários da sua pergunta.
 Fico no aguardo do feedBack.

Comment: obrigado, vou aplicar sua ideia no meu projeto

Comment: Oi,não deu certo, ele continua repetindo, coloco ele  dentro da tag body ou antes?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Esqueci de colocar, porque usei o jsFiddle que não precisa colocar o body.

Comment: Certo no momento estou no serviço e não tenho como conferir mas ontem não tinha dado certo tentarei assim que voltar da aula. Obrigado

Comment: @Malfus todos os eventos de ação tem que ser no body. Fico no aguardo do feedBack

Comment: Certo, só vou conseguir te dar o feedback a noite. Grato pela ajuda